# Conditionally switch between states (Angular, ui-router)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router and have two states with different logic and want to conditionally switch between them.

First state is dictionary.tableView, and the second one is dictionary.fileView, user must choose which variant is more appropriate for him in aplication settings.

How I can conditionally switch between  these states?

I need generate common url, e.g. /view/2, and redirect to /table/2 or /file-browser/2 on click depend on user settings.

Comment: you can pass the state name to transition to as a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically change to the state in the controller:

```
<a ng-click="changeState()">Go</a>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.changeState = function(){
    if (..) {
        $state.go("table");
    } else {
        $state.go("file");
    }
}
```

Comment: you can add [this documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) to answer, might be helpful.